# Does any dialect of Pascal allow a variable number of arguments?

Tags: language-features, pascal

This is a question for the *older* programmers.

Years ago, I encountered a dialect of Pascal which allowed a variable number of arguments, through some kind of extension.

Does anyone know of a current dialect of Pascal which allows a variable number of arguments?

Given that Pascal is not as popular as it used to be, I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is no.

BTW, it *is* more correct, isn't it, to say variable number of *arguments*, rather than *parameters* ?

Comment: Yes it is, more correct to say variable number of arguments, the function can have only one parameter which is a variable list of arguments, usually as the last parameter

Comment: I like that way of thinking about it: 'one parameter which is a variable list of parameters' +1 (but you're not really *old enough* ;-D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The answer is based on the Pascal dialects that I have used; others may be different.

The reason is that Pascal pushes arguments onto the stack frame in order, so all arguments are accessed via a fixed offset from the stack pointer. C, by comparison, pushes arguments in reverse order, so defined parameters are at fixed offset, and you can access "extra" arguments via pointer arithmetic. I'll try some ASCII art:

```
        Pascal                  C

                                ---------------------
                                |     extra arg     |
        ---------------------   ---------------------
        |     1st param     |   |     3rd param     |
        ---------------------   ---------------------
        |     2nd param     |   |     2nd param     |
        ---------------------   ---------------------
SP ->   |     3rd param     |   |     1st param     |
        ---------------------   ---------------------
```

As for parameter versus argument: as I learned it, the function (method) defines its parameters, the caller passes arguments. That definition came, I believe, from a Fortran manual, so that should give you an idea of how old I am :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find some description of the internals of Apollo DOMAIN Pascal, the dialect which allowed variable lists of arguments (and which I'm *still* using). Your explanation has the ring of truth about it.

Comment: If you're still using it, you should be able to disassemble an example with different calling sequences. I wouldn't be surprised if they use the C calling conventions.

Comment: For Apollo documentation, see here: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/apollo/

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional arguments with delphi to get the same effect:

```
procedure Proc(const A: Integer; const B: Integer = 15);

Proc(10);  // B = 15
Proc(20,30);
```

Or overloaded methods:

```
procedure Proc(const A: Integer); overload;
procedure Proc(const A,B: Integer); overload;

Proc(10);     // Variant 1
Proc(20,30);  // Variant 2
```

Or you can use a variable array for parameters:

```
procedure Message(const AMessage: string; const AArgs: array of const);

Message('Hello %s', [Name]);
Message('%s %s', [Greeting, Name]);
```

Comment: Great, I just qualified myself as old ;-).

Comment: It looks like you're explicitly constructing the array in your second example, correct?

Comment: @Gamecat, I'll put it down to your 30 years experience, although there's nothing wrong with *age*. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GNU-Pascal (gcc based) afaik maps 1:1 to C support. using function something(arg:pchar;...) like syntax

Delphi/Free Pascal has "array of const" support, which is a typesafe version, and a varargs directive for the C interfacing (D6 or D7+)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of a library that was available for Turbo Pascal where they had a hack like this.  My syntax is a bit a rusty for objects and descending from it.

```
type
  TValue = object;

  TInteger = object(TValue)
    Value : Integer;
  end

  TString = object(TValue)
    Value : String;
  end

  TParam = record
    Value : TValue;
    Param : TParam;
  end;

  TValue = object;

{ Definition of Function }
function Test (Arg : TParam);

{ Usage }
var
  I : TInteger;
  S : TString;

Test (TParam (I, TParam (S, nil));
```

You could just chain as many arguments as you wanted.  The last one had to be terminated with nil.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Use the `params` keyword:

```pascal
procedure write(params args: array of Object);
begin
  {...}
end;
```

Comment: What dialect is it?

Comment: @Doj PascalABC.NET